# How to bind value to variables of objects which are present in a list

Tags: list, jsp, object, binding, struts2

I have a FormObject that contains a list of objects.

I want to bind value to variables of objects which are in list.

---

```
class Form{
 List<QualityCheck> quality;
 //setter and getters..
}

class QulaityCheck{
   GreetingStandard greetingStandard;
   ..
//setter and getters..
}

 class GreetingStandard{
  int opening;
  ..
 //setter and getters..}
```

---

I have tried this:

```
<s:textfield name="form.quality[%{#rowStatus.index}].greetingStandard.opening"/>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20856600/573032

Comment: edit content for legibility; edit title for simplicity